# How to revert back my local changes using Git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I am working on Git and did lots of changes to a particular file. By mistake, while committing I ran git stash and all changes made to that file are gone now. Is there any way to bring those changes back??
I used git stash show and git stash apply but it's not working.

Comment: `git stash list` should show you all stash changes. `git stash pop` will apply the top change to working directory.

Comment: refer this link https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/restore-repo-to-previous-revision

Comment: I am getting this when use got stash pop: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        src/main/java/restAPIFramework/com/rest/service/Service.java
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.

Comment: Okay. You have more changes in that file. Either you can commit those changes `git add /path/to/file && git commit -m {message}` or you have discard those changes `git checkout -- /path/to/file`(check the changes using `git diff` before doing this one). Once you have completed prior steps, then you should be able to `git stash pop`

Answer (score 1):

`git stash pop`

can be used with here to get back your changes.

git stash apply --index

If the --index option is used, then tries to reinstate not only the working tree’s changes, but also the index’s ones. However, this can fail, when you have conflicts